# Show Uniform Convergence of $f_n(x)=n^2x^n(1-x)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x)=n^2x^n(1-x)^2$ on $[0,a]$ where $a<1$

I know that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f=0$

Uniformly converge iff:
for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $n>N$ s.t. 
$|f_n-f|<\epsilon$

So I should show that I can find $n$ such that
$|f_n-f|=|n^2x^n(1-x)^2-0|<\epsilon$ for all $0\leq x \leq a$

> I already showed that it is not uniformly convergent on [0,1] by taking $f_n(1-1/n)$ because $(1-1/n)^n$ is 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bounded on $[0,a]$ by $n^2a^n$, which converges to $0$ without depending on $x$.

Comment: So I need to find $n^2a^n<\epsilon$  which is always possible since the exponential decreases faster than the term $n^2$? I don't seem to pinpoint this $n$

Comment: The function $x^2a^x$ has a maximum for $x=-2/\log a$.

Comment: I was doing this question again, and when I differentiate $x^2a^x$ and set to $0$ I get $x=-2\log x / \log a$, could you tell me where this term goes?

Comment: ?? There's no $\log x$  when you differentiate $x^2a^x$. What do you mean?

Comment: $(d)/(dx)(x^2 a^x) = x a^x (x log(a)+2)$ this is by Wolfram Alpha

Comment: I agree, but there's no $\log x$.

Comment: I must have done it incorrectly :(

Answer (score 1):

A hint is to analyze the functions $f_n(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$, while keeping in mind that you really only care about what happens on $[0,a]$. Find the derivative, it's zeroes and try to graph the function. It might be useful to start with say $f_3(x)$, and then consider the general case $f_n(x)$ afterwards.

Knowing the shape and properties of the sequence of functions can go a long way in "guessing" an $n_\epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon > 0$.